# Откуда берутся файлы? scss в шаблоне

Tags: html, css, scss

Скачал в инете шаблон, навожу исследовать элемент и подучаю источник стилей с файлов _header.scss
У меня таких файлов в проекте нету, откуда они берутся? Где про это почитать?
И как на это влиять, переопределять или убирать?

[image: Откуда файлы]

Comment: Наведите мышку на названия этих файлов (вот там, куда указывают красные стрелки на скриншоте) и увидите место, где хранятся эти файлы. Соответственно, поймете, откуда они взялись.

Comment: в том то и дело ,что их там нет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего в конце собранных css файлов указан sourceMap. Удобно использовать для читаемости кода, если исходные файлы прошли различные стадии оптимизации, минификации.

https://habr.com/ru/post/509250/